# Add parameter to AJAX in Classic ASP

Tags: html, ajax, asp-classic

In addition to "PaymentID" need to add another parameter to exiting AJAX call for variable "CurrUserID", see existing code below:

```
<script>
     function cback_<%=objRS("PaymentID")%>(text) 
              document.getElementById('tr_<%=objRS("PaymentID")%>').innerHTML = text;
      }
      doAjax('/receipt_ajax.asp','PaymentID=<%=objRS("PaymentID")%>','cback_<%=objRS("PaymentID")%>','get','0')
</script>
```

Need help on Syntax, I have tried adding comma plus Parmenter and concatenating using & or +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL syntax is `page.asp?key1=val1&key2=val2`, so your code most likely needs to be

```
doAjax('/receipt_ajax.asp',
'PaymentID=<%=objRS("PaymentID")%>&CurrUserID=<%=objRS("CurrUserID")%>'
```

where <%= %> injects the server side value to output the value of objRS("CurrUserID"). If all is correct, the page code will get

```
 doAjax('/receipt_ajax.asp','PaymentID=...&CurrUserID=...'
```

[More on asp syntax here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/inline-expressions)